# Rails: How not to escape in "<title>" tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I developed Rails app.

Characters such as `&` are escaped to `&amp;` in `<title>` tag.

For example,`foo & bar` is displayed such as `foo &amp; bar` in the title.

When I use `raw`, it can be displayed as I expect. But I don't want to use `raw` because the data will be inputted by the user.

I'd like to display like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417510/symfony-2-twig-how-not-to-escape-field-value-used-with-backbonejs-symfony-2) (Pls see only title. Contents is nothing to do with my question).  `&` is displayed in the title in spite of inputted by the user.

My code is as below.

**application.html.erb**

```
<head>
  <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
  ...
```

**application_helper.rb**

```
  def full_title(page_title = '')
    base_title = "app name"
    if page_title.empty?
      base_title
    else
      page_title + " | " + base_title
    end
  end
```

I added `provide` in some view files, such as **show.html.erb**.

```
<% provide(:title, @schedule.title) %>  #this title is inputted by user
```

Is it possible to escape it, but allow some characters unescaped?

Comment: use `.html_safe` method

Comment: .html_safe is the equivalent of using raw. Never use it with user input.

Comment: I'm confused. So do you want to escape or not?

Comment: Do you want to escape it, but allow some characters unescaped?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and sorry for unclear question, @Vasfed. As you commented, I think I'd like to allow some characters unescaped.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and sorry for unclear question, @ Sergio Tulentsev. As Vasfed commented, I think I'd like to allow some characters unescaped.

Comment: `&` has to be escaped as `&amp;`, the `<title>` tag is no exception. If your browser shows `&amp;` literally, you have most likely escaped it twice. BTW, the linked post's title tag is `<title>symfony2 - Symfony 2, Twig: how not to escape field value (used with backbonejs &amp; symfony 2) - Stack Overflow</title>`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Stefan. Could it be that it depends on browser?. I use crome.

Answer (score 1):

You ask how to avoid escaping, but it sounds like what you *really* want is for browsers to display "`&`" instead of "`&amp;`".

If you use your browser's "View Source" feature on [the page you said looked right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417510/symfony-2-twig-how-not-to-escape-field-value-used-with-backbonejs-symfony-2), you will see that it begins with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QAPage">
<head>

<title>symfony2 - Symfony 2, Twig: how not to escape field value (used with backbonejs &amp; symfony 2) - Stack Overflow</title>
```

Observe that ampersand is entity-encoded as `&amp;` just the way it "should" be.

Observe that the document begins with a DOCTYPE declaration. A document that begins with something else will probably trigger the browser's [quirks mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) for compatibility.

Use your browser's "View Source" function on your Rails application. Does the document begin with a DOCTYPE declaration? (`<DOCTYPE html>` is good.) Does the sequence `&amp;` appear on its own? (If you see `&amp;amp;` or similar, you're encoding an already-encoded string.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @RJHunter. My html begins with `<!DOCTYPE html>`. And it shows `<title>foo &amp;amp; bar</title>`.

Comment: If your application is sending "&amp;amp;" to the browser, then your application is escaping something that has already been escaped. For example, maybe the input part of your application HTML-escapes the content before storing it in the database. Later, the display part of your application reads the content from the database and HTML-escapes it for putting in HTML.